# How to programmatically click on a button and after a particular time in Javascript and jQuery | Bypass popup blocking in web Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was developing an application that programmatically shows a popup after 5 seconds, but i found out that web browsers like firefox, chrome, internet explorer, etc. were blocking the popup.

**Popup blocking**
In the past, evil sites abused popups a lot. A bad page could open tons of popup windows with ads. So now most browsers try to block popups and protect the user.

**Most browsers block popups if they are called outside of user-triggered event handlers like** `onclick`

By default modern web browsers block popups triggered by a function or code. But does not block popups triggered by clicking on buttons.

```
// popup blocked
window.open('https://javascript.info');

// popup allowed
button.onclick = () => {
  window.open('https://javascript.info');
};
```

So i had to bypass their blocking policy by programmatically clicking on the button after 5 seconds to still initiate the same popup.

So i decided to post this as a question and also answer it by myself for those that might be facing the same issue.

**Step 1.**
Create a button, give it and ID and pass a function name on the `onClick`

```
<button id="buttonID" onclick="trigerPopup()"></button>
```

**Step 2**
Create `trigerPopup` function

```
function trigerPopup(){
        alert("Hello I am poping up after 5 seconds");
        //your code goes here
}
```

**Step 3**
After 5 seconds, programmatically clicked on button

```
    window.setTimeout(function () {

        //this will trigger a click on the button
        const buttonID = document.getElementById('buttonID').click();


   }, 5000);
```

Thanks guys

Comment: can't you disply the pop-up/modal by css? Displaying a popup by feaking a click event sounds a bit shady. The click event has a trusted value so the browser can easly figure out if the click really was done by the user or by a javascript itself so there is a possibility that this will also not work for some users or when the browsers have an update

Comment: @Baracuda078 This type of popup has nothing to do with CSS. It's a kind of popup implemented by popup ADS

Comment: You could display it in an iframe if the host allow that

Comment: @Baracuda078 Yes you are right. It's an iframe popup

Comment: @Baracuda078 To bypass host or browser blocking the popup. This is where programmatically clicking on the button will save

Comment: @Baracuda078 You can use CSS or Javascript to hide the button

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1.**
Create a button, give it and ID and pass a function name on the `onClick`

```
<button id="buttonID" onclick="trigerPopup()"></button>
```

**Step 2**
Create `trigerPopup` function

```
function trigerPopup(){
        alert("Hello I am poping up after 5 seconds");
        //your code goes here
}
```

**Step 3**
After 5 seconds, programmatically clicked on button

```
    window.setTimeout(function () {

        //this will trigger a click on the button
        const buttonID = document.getElementById('buttonID').click();


   }, 5000);
```

Comment: Unclear how `alert` is the same as `window.open()`

Comment: @epascarello I used alert for example purpose. You can replace alert() with windows.open

Comment: A pop up blocker is going to block this. A pop up window has to be initialized by a USER ACTION. The button click is not from a use action. Where is the pop up? https://jsfiddle.net/L2pj0xfr/